# Applying filter to 2 Tabbed Forms

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am coming across error 438 when running code to open 2 tabbed forms from 1 reference ID from another form; It opens the forms correct with the looks of the Data but shows the error -

> Error Number: 438
> Object doesn't support this property or method

I believe the error to be as to .filter isn't working, because a filter is already applied - however the results look correct as current the 2 sub tabbed forms open on the correct record but the error still shows every time

I would like the below code to run without the error can anyone make any suggestions - (not just error handling to ignore error)

```
Public Function Open()

On Error GoTo Err_LogError

Dim stLinkCriteria As String
Dim stLinkCriteria1 As String

stLinkCriteria = "[CaseID]=" & Me![ID]
stLinkCriteria1 = "[CaseID]=" & Me![ID]

Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form.Visible = True
Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveTasks.SetFocus
Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveTasks.Form.Filter = stLinkCriteria
Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveTasks.Form.FilterOn = True

Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form.Visible = True
Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveInfo.SetFocus
Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveInfo.Form.Filter = stLinkCriteria1
Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveInfo.Form.FilterOn = True

Exit Function

Err_LogError:
Call ErrorHandle

End Function
```

Comment: No, the filter is not the cause of the error. Where do you call the `Open()` function?

Comment: The code works on 1 form but not two when testing code individually - this function runs based on double click of another form

Comment: Put a breakpoint, step through and see which line throws the error.

Comment: 'Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveInfo.Form.Filter = stLinkCriteria1' - is where the error occurs but is needed - as stated the full function looks like it still runs but gives the error - The second part of the code does give desired result if removed

Comment: That denotes error accessing the `.Form` property of the `frmLiveInfo` control. This probably means the form has not been loaded, but I'm not sure. Haven't work with tab controls for quite sometime.

Comment: If I swap the order of 'frmLiveTasks' and 'frmLiveTasks'  the error would now occur in the 'frmLiveTasks' part of the code so it is definitely the second tab controls that is the issue

Comment: Edit question to show exact error message, not just number, as well as the line triggering error. Disable error handler during debugging. What do you mean by "swap the order of 'frmLiveTasks' and 'frmLiveTasks'" - since these are same name what is swapped? Are frmTabs, frmLiveInfo, frmLiveTasks the names of subform container controls? I always name containers different from the objects they hold. If a filter is already applied, how is it?

Comment: The tabbed form is called frmTabs and the subforms called frmLiveInfo and frmLiveTasks.

Comment: Question updated - I meant switched the order of the blocks of code so ' Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form.Visible = True Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveInfo.SetFocus Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveInfo.Form.Filter = stLinkCriteria1 Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveInfo.Form.FilterOn = True' - came before the 'Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form.Visible = True Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveTasks.SetFocus Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveTasks.Form.Filter = stLinkCriteria1 Forms!frmHome!frmTabs.Form!frmLiveTasks.Form.FilterOn = True' code - the error occurred in the second section still

Comment: Again, what are names of the container controls? Are they the same as the objects they hold? Must be since one of the blocks works because referencing must use the container names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It transpired that the code worked - but the error was linked to another section of VBA